# How to create popup window to create new record in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, popup, ruby-on-rails-3.1

We have a requirement where the web page displays all the records from joining few tables.
We have an "Add Button" - upon clicking the button, I have to display an popup window, where user will enter the necessary details. The popup will have two buttons Save and Cancel.

Clicking Save button, should validate the fields and if all validations are passed, then save the record to database else display the error messages in alert boxes.

Clicking Cancel button will close the popup window.

How do I create popup upon clicking add button?

Comment: You need JavaScript. The popup may use the standard controller actions (`edit`,`new`,`update`..). I am sorry for giving you only rough directions, but the first thing you may do is to investigate how to use JavaScript to create a popup, fetch some HTML, send a form. AJAX in other words. And MySQL is not important here.

Comment: 1. how do i link controller actions from the popup?
2. how do i close the popup?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to separate the things that are server-side (Rails, controllers, actions) and client-side (popups, JavaScript, sending requests).

Your client-side actions (JavaScript code) should think about your Rails application as about *some* server, which returns *some* responses for *some* requests. From JavaScript's point of view it is not important whether the server is running Rails or Smalltalk.

The basic workflow for your popup may be:

**1) open a new window** - This requires *client-side* activity of JavaScript. Use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) function, or (I humbly consider this method a better one) [create a new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) `<div>` and style it with CSS so it will cover (a nice effect is an half-opaque background: `background: #ddf; opacity: 0.5;`, through which you still see the content of the page).

**2) fill the window with an edit form** - Here your *client-side* script should make an AJAX-like call *(not necessarily real AJAX, since in this case a synchronic request may be sensible)* to get the edit form from your Rails application. See this simplicated example:

```
function fillPopupBody(popup) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET","/something/partial_new_form.html",false); // Synchronic request!
  req.send(null);
  if( req.status == 200 ) {
    popup.innerHTML = req.responseText;
    return true;
  } else {
    popup.innerHTML = "<p class='error'>"+req.status+" ("+req.statusText+")</p>";
    return false;
  }
}
```

**3) Prepare the form-returning action in your Rails application** - *(server-side)* Usually this may be your `new` action of the given resource controller, but rendered without layout.

An alternative approach would be to build the form by the JavaScript (without fetching it separately), or to include it always in the page - just hidden by default, so the JavaScript needs only to set its `display` property.

**4) Handle form submission** - you probably want the user to stay on the same page, so you should intercept the form submission. Just add a handler to the "submit" event of the created form, build a request, post it, check the server response.

The **response will be returned by Rails, by your :create action**. You may already have it ready, because the code created by `./script/rails generate scaffold` is usually OK.

If the response is 201 (created), you may close the popup (`display: none`) and update the page to display the new object - either refresh the whole page, or fetch only the changed parts.

If the `create` action cannot create the object, by default the response code is 422 (unprocessable entity) and the content is the model errors object, rendered as JSON or XML. Just display the errors in the form (let your JavaScript set the `innerHTML` of some predefined element).

---

That was the 'manual' way of doing the task. I have some aversion (hardly explainable ;-) to JavaScript libraries, and I prefer to work directly with DOM. You may find a lot of Rails helpers which will save you from writing JavaScript code. I guess that looking at the `:remote => true` parameter of `form_for` will be a good starting point.

Also the jQuery documentation ( http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page ) may be a good thing to read.

Ending this long story, here are the *short* answers to your questions from the comment:

> How do i link controller actions from the popup?

: By sending a HTTP request to the proper URL: "GET /users/1/notes/new", "POST /user/1/notes"

> How do i close the popup?

: By setting `display: none` if the popup is an element of the page, or by calling `window.close()` if your popup is a separate window.

Answer (score 1):

I made it as follow:

To Open a window:

```
<%= link_to "Agregar Modelos", {:controller => "educationals", :action => "index4", :id => params[:id]}, :popup => ['Modelo Educacional', 'height=300,width=600'] %>
```

To Close the window after submit:

```
<%= submit_tag "Aceptar", :onclick => "window.close()" %>
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me, it creates an a tag with the attribute `popup` which seems to be invalid.

Comment: Sadly, apparently that option (:popup) was removed :(
https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4408872